# How to start C++ ETL (Embedded Template Library) with VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, g++

Could anyone point a getting started with Embedded Template Library with VS Code?
It seems there is no google results for it. (Windows)

Step 0:
I can use VS Code with g++ and gcc and VS Code in Windows and successfully run and debug C++ / STL code.

Step 1:
I've downloaded from [ETL from github](https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl).

**Question**

Now this is exactly the point where I got stuck :-), now what?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `"getting started"`?  The [`README.md`](https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl#readme) has the build/install instructions and there are also various [examples](https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl/tree/master/examples).

Comment: I've read the readme, multiple times. I do not know how the cmake part applies to a vs code project, and in case it applies what to write to launch.json. Regarding the setup only a link is in the readme, what leads to etl site, where not a single word written about the bultd. Obviously I a beginner in how to build, how to use any C++ related toolchain. The only thing I know is the C++ language itself, and I installed gcc and can successfully compile, debug a one file C++ source. I supposed etl is avaiilable in the form of binaries and the header files, so I can use it similatly to stl.

Comment: @g.pickardou: No, like the STL (back in 1995 when it still existed), the ETL is header-only. No binaries required. Just `#include`.

Comment: OK, my bad. This worth an answer, in case you have intention to write an answer.